# how to display collectionview in second view when i tap on tableview any cell in first view

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi i am displaying tableview when i tap on tableview any cell i want to display collection view with images.but here i am getting blank view in second view not to display images in collection view.
my code is like this

```
viewDidLoad{
freshArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],[UIImage  imageNamed:@"4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],nil];

popularArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],nil];

AdviceArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"19.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"20.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"21.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"22.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"23.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"24.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"25.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"26.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"27.png"],nil];
AllitemsArray=[[NSMutableArray  alloc]initWithObjects:freshArray,popularArray,AdviceArray,AwesomeArray,CartoonArray, nil];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
secondViewController *second=[[secondViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];   
second.recipeImageView.image=[AllitemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
second.secCollectionImagesArray=AllitemsArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
secondViewController.m
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [secCollectionImagesArray count];

}
- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110];

[descLabel setText:[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[secCollectionImagesArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

int pages = floor(collectionView.contentSize.width / collectionView.frame.size.width) + 1;
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:pages];

return cell;
}
any help Appreciated
```

Comment: Please check first your data source and delegates are given properly or not. Then give background color of your collection view to check if it is there. Then check the value of your array count see if there are values in it. Then load data in collectionview.

Comment: i gave delegate and datasourse.and i have chosen bicolor default

Comment: i think my mistake is array parsing if i give like this second.secCollectionImagesArray=AllitemsArray; in did select row at index path getting crash.if don't give this line display second view with empty scrren

Comment: plz suggest me how to do this

Comment: If you put this line second.secCollectionImagesArray=AllitemsArray, then check the values of your array you are passing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your secondview where your collectionview is and check the value of secCollectionImagesArray in nslog.

Comment: but when i tap on tableview Cell getting crash

Comment: like -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ohh this is wrong... NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.jpg",@"b.jpg", nil]; Try to give values to array like this...

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:110];

Or
It looks like you have subclassed the collectionviewcell then you can access UIImageView and uilabel like this 
cell.label=@"text";

Comment: I haven't compiled the code. I just typed in my mobile. It should work.

Comment: nw i am displaying CollectionView when i tap any tableview cell

Comment: but my issue is getting crash when i selected perticular image in collectionView which should be next view my code is-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    third=[[thirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"thirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    
   third.inputImage=[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    [self presentViewController:third animated:YES completion:nil];
    
  NSLog(@" selected data ==%@",[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: getting this issue [__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance